# Manage multiple Retrofit calls such that update UI based on last API call and cancel previous calls

Tags: android, google-maps, concurrency, retrofit2

I use Retrofit2 to get information for an specified location selected on map and display it on my application UI by calling method `getLabelFromServer` as below.

Since user may change selected location while I'm waiting to receive information from server, I should cancel previous call to received information and wait to receive information for new location and update UI upon response for new call.
Please note that previous call should not update UI since it will display information for previous location which is not selected by user now.
How can I change below code to achieve this (I should note I call this method on UI thread every time new location is selected on map).

```
 private void getLabelFromServer(Context ctx, GeoPoint geoPoint) {
    MapServiceGenerator serviceGenerator = MapServiceGenerator.getInstance(ctx, null);
    Call<JsonObject> call = serviceGenerator.getGeoCodeApi().getAddress(geoPoint.getLatitude() + "," + geoPoint.getLongitude());
    call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
                     @Override
                     public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                         JsonObject result = response.body();
                         String positionLabel = MapUtils.generateLabelFromJSON(result);
                         tvLabel.setText(positionLabel);
                     }

                     @Override
                     public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                         if (t != null) {
                             t.printStackTrace();
                         } 
                     }
                 }
    );
}
```

Comment: check call.isExecuted(); method before giving the next request.
if it returns true your request has been completed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check call.isExecuted(); method before giving the next request.
if it returns true your request has been completed.
else, it has not been completed so call call.cancel() method to cancel the request and re initiate your request again

Comment: Do you know, what would be the result if I call `call.cancel()` if `call.isExecuted()` is true at the moment? Does it raise an exception or it would run without no problem?